# In Querydsl - Is it possible to join an entity with java collection

Tags: querydsl

Have a list (userIds) with id and QUser which has an id field. Is it possible in querydsl to join the QUser id field to id field in the list.

```
    QUser qUser = new QUser("userUnEncrypted");

    QUserEncryptedColumns qUserEncryptedColumns = new QUserEncryptedColumns("userEncryptedColumns");
    List<Long> userIds = new ArrayList<>();

    for (UserEncryptedColumns user : from(qUserEncryptedColumns,userEncryptedData)
        .where(ExpressionUtils.predicate(expr.getOperator(), args))  // Filtering my collection inside a ReplaceVisitor inside visit method based on the predicate etc...
        .fetch()){
        userIds.add(user.getId());
    }
```

Now I have to join the QUser - something like below to get all the users but limited to the ones available in my collection....

trying not to use the where in condition...as it could be a very huge list

```
    .select()
    .from(qUser)
    .innerJoin(........)
```

Comment: Could you please update the question with a code sample?

Comment: When you say 'huge' - how huge do you mean?
I have used expressions like `where(qUser.id.in(userIds))` for lists of length 10000 without issues.
Alternatively write them to a table and join using that.